# Firebase iOS - searching database for dictionaries with specific ID value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database managed solely via iOS of the following format in Firebase:

`hotels/
    hotel1/
        guests/
            *[RandomID]:guest1
            [RandomID]:guest2
            [RandomID]:guest3
        location/
        address
        ...
    hotel2/
        guests/
            [RandomID]:guest3
            [RandomID]:guest4
        location/
        address
        ...
    hotel3/
        guests/
        location/
        address
        ...
    hotel4/
        guests/
            [RandomID]:guest4
            [RandomID]:guest5
        location/
        address
        ...
    hotel5/
        guests/
            [RandomID]:guest3
        location/
        address
        ...
    ...`

My goal is to run a Swift command to return the set of 'hotels' that have a given guest. For example, checking for guest3 should return hotels 1, 2, and 5 with associated data. Something along the lines of this would typically work:

`Query filterQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("type").equalTo(true);`

but unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there is an equivalent to the `equalTo` command in the iOS documentation. What is the best way to accomplish this task in the bounds of the iOS Firebase library then?

*The random IDs are generated automatically when the guest entry is inserted into the guests dictionary, as per this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html. It seems unintuitive, but apparently uniqueness must be ensured by assigning each element a unique ID generated at insertion time.

Comment: David's answer is indeed the most common approach: store the data in both directions. I just answered a [question about this in an AskFirebase video](https://youtu.be/HjlQH3RsGcU?t=2m45s). If you're more a reader, here's the answer that video covers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just have another set for users and then for each user have the hotels that they are a value of?

Something along these lines

```
users:
    - guest1:
        - hotels:
            - hotel1
            - hotel3
            - etc. etc.
```

I doubt it would be good to have to go through every hotel to see if it contains a certain user. This way you could just call the user based on their `[RandomID]` and get the hotels that way.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
let query = ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: guestID)
            query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            }
```

> here ref = reference to hotels branch