# List categories and belonging products from separate nodes in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm developing an Ionic 2 App using Firebase as Backend.

I have a categories and products structure. Products belong to categories. As it is a "n to m" relationship, products and categories are stored in separate nodes in firebase. I structured the data as follows:

Firebase data structure:

[image: 1]

Categories know, which products belong to them (keys are referenced in "prods" node of each category).
Products know, which categories they belong to (keys are referenced in the "prod_cat" node).

In the template I want to list all categories and the belonging products. However, I can't get it running. I tried the following:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let cat of categories">
  <h3 *ngIf="cat.parent_cat === 'noParentCategory'">
    {{cat.cat_name}}
  </h3>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let subcat of categories">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item-divider *ngIf="subcat.parent_cat === cat.$key">
        {{subcat.cat_name}}
      </ion-item-divider>
      <ng-container *ngIf="subcat.prods">

          <ng-container *ngFor="let product of products">
            <ion-item *ngIf="product.$key === subcat.prods">
              {{product.prod_name}}
            </ion-item>
          </ng-container>

      </ng-container>
    </ion-list>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

I know, that the problem is in this line:

```
<ion-item *ngIf="product.$key === subcat.prods">
```

I need to say "**IF** product.$key **IS IN** subcat.prods, **then**...". How can I do this??

Comment: I tried a different approach: Instead of combining categories and products in the view, i tried to do it in the *.js file. However, still struggeling there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349131/angularfire2-perform-joins-on-firebaselistobservables-using-rxjs-map

Comment: Solved it with a slightly different approach:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349131/angularfire2-perform-joins-on-firebaselistobservables-using-rxjs-map

Comment: The most general data model for many to many relation ship in firebase is discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase