# Firebase social media app: saving groups of users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

In a Firebase social-media-esque app, here is how I'm storing groups along with its members:
[image]

Here, I have a reciprocating relationship in terms of memberships of groups. A group knows all of the users that are a part of it in `group-users` and vise-versa—a user knows all of the groups it's in via `user-groups`. The reason I thought to do this is it seems to be quick for a user to access all of its groups, and likewise it seems to be quick for a group to access all of its users. However, having this reciprocating data is costly in terms of space. My other option would be to keep just the `user-groups` node, and to retrieve all the members of a single group I would need to query that node by group ID. This option seems slower but would take less space in the database. Which option is more advised? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best data model always depends on the use-cases of your app. If you need access to both the groups-for-a-user and the users-for-a-group, the cheapest way to do so is to store both.

See:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [the answer to this question in a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjlQH3RsGcU&t=165s)
- this article about [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- the Firebase video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)