# Firebase functions not listening for specific path

Tags: function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a path in database `/business/{businessId}/images/{imageId}/imageUrl`
It listens for `business` when a business in created, but later I'm pushing images in `images`, but it doesn't listen for `businessImages`. I used below listeners.

```
exports.business = functions.database.ref('/business/{businessId}').onWrite(event => {
    console.log('lorem epsum****', event);
    return true;
});

exports.businessImages = functions.database.ref('/business/{businessId}/images/{imageId}/imageUrl').onWrite(event => {
    console.log('lorem epsum****', event);
    return true;
});
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried removing imageUrl at the end?

Comment: Yup, tried even removing {imageId}. Still didn't work.

Comment: Please update your question to include your database structure.

Comment: If it possible that businessImages isn't firing because business is firing since it's watching a node higher up. Can you confirm whether or not exports.business fires when you write to any node below {businessId}?

Comment: I've mentioned already
/business/{businessId}/images/{imageId}/imageUrl
like
`https://console.firebase.google.com/project/xxxxxxxx/database/data/business/-KxmM4e8pWKElDOcfD-b/images/-KxmM4gne1tl0yBbtJ_B/imageUrl`

Comment: @DoesData Yeah, but it still doesn't work even if I remove `business` function.

Comment: Include your database structure and the code where you write to the DB.

Comment: Isn't this database structure?
`/business/-Kxm‌​M4e8pWKElDOcfD-b/ima‌​ges/-KxmM4gne1tl0yBb‌​tJ_B/imageUrl`

Comment: No. Go to your Firebase console and take a screenshot of the data so we can see where you are writing / listening for data changes. We can't verify that your path is correct without seeing the structure. You can take a look at a question I asked that includes images of the structure here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008814/efficiently-determine-if-user-liked-post-in-firebase

Comment: Show database screenshot please

Comment: @InzamamMalik https://www.screencast.com/t/J1nJMPFYe9wb

Comment: @MohammadKashifSulaiman if you want to trigger when an image is added apply trigger on `/business/{businessId}/images/{imageId}`

Comment: instead of `/business/{businessId}/images/{imageId}/imageUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one for the answers, but the main issue was, i was inserting the whole base 64 images in the imageUrl, resulting in slowest performance for listening or getting data for imageUrl. When i removed all the images, it worked great.

P.S. I know we should put URLs instead of base 64 images.