# How to delete a specific child from a child in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application where a user can create lists.

The user can share a list with other users. I already manage to create the sharing part, the one I'm having issues is with the delete part. I want that when a user deletes a list that is shared , this list is also deleted from the other users.

This delete will be made only by list owner.

So a scenario will be:

- User A creates a List with pushID = 1.
- This list is added in the following firebase ref: /userList/$userAID/$pushID.
- User A shares list with User B and User C.
- This list is added in the following firebase ref: /userList/$userBID/$pushID and /userList/$userCID/$pushID.
- User A deletes list with pushID = 1.

So in my

So i have this schema:

```
userList: {
   2xYnKcZFEdPYWfUJ3E63yQEDShe2: {
     -Kt7lXiY0Yt-oDcV38L5
   }
   KtQHkXMSwKSByZ1rmTRwjDmSYnE3: {
     -Kt7lXiY0Yt-oDcV38L5: {}
     -Kt9XP91hjwcwgcBSgbc: {}
   }
   XHpMVoRqcCdzwTP70L29Lza1ibD3: {
     -Kt7lXiY0Yt-oDcV38L5: {}
   }
}
```

In high level this will be:

```
userList: {
       userID: (A) {
         -listID : (1) {}
       }
       userID: (B) {
         -listID: (1) {}
         -listID: (2) {}
       }
       userID: (C) {
         -listID: (1) {}
         -listID: (3) {}
         -listID: (4) {}
       }
    }
```

The current code I have to do this is the following:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('userList');
    ref.once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          ref.child(childSnapshot.key)
            .once('value')
            .then((snapshot2) => {
              snapshot2.forEach((childSnapshot2) => {
                if (childSnapshot2.key === uid) {
                  ref.child(childSnapshot2.key)
                    .remove();
                }
              });
            })
            .catch(() => {
              console.log('error2');
            });
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

What I'm doing in this code is, first fetching ALL the list inside userList, by getting the key I manage to jump to the userID child. Inside this node once again I manage to jump inside the pushID where I make a validation of checking if current key is equal to the UID of the list i want to delete, if so I do a remove().

I feel there must be a better way of telling Firebase to go directly to pushID and find all of those that are equal to the UID of the list I want to delete and then do it.

Comment: Im looking for something like:
firebase.database().ref('userList').child().child(uid).remove();

I know child() can't be empty. But something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do a server-side delete of multiple items based on a condition with the Firebase Database. You must first retrieve the items (or just their IDs) matching the condition and then delete those.

However, you **can** delete the list itself and all references to it in one go by using a multi-path update.

I'd also recommend keeping a list of all the UIDs you've shared a specific list with, so that you don't have to loop over all users. Keeping many-to-many relations in both directions is quite common in Firebase and other NoSQL databases.

For more see:

- the [blog post introducing multi-path updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)
- the [blog post describing client-side fan-out using multi-path updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)
- my answer on [strategies for updating denormalized data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase)
- my answer on [modeling many-to-many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)

Comment: Yeah, at the end I figure the best way will be keeping a record of all users the list is been shared and with that loop to delete.
But what would you think is best practice ... using the milti-path update or having a list of all users you are sharing with and then loop?

Comment: The two typically go hand-in-hand: you read the list of locations/keys from the database, loop over that to build a collection of paths to update and then fire a single multi-location update.