# Accessing array in component from ionic view

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template, angularfire2

```
this.tribesProvider.getMyTribeDetailsByTriberId().subscribe(tribeIds=>{
     tribeIds.forEach(tribeId=>{
         this.tribesProvider.getMyTribeDetailsByTribeId(tribeId).subscribe(tribe=>{
             this.myTribeList.push(tribe);
             console.log(this.myTribeList);
         })

     })
 })
```

I have to  access the array *myTribeList* from its view like this

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let tribe of myTribeList">
    <ion-list>
      <h2>{{tribe.TribeDesc}}</h2>
      <h2>{{tribe.TribeName}}</h2>
      <h2>{{tribe.Created}}</h2>
      <h2>{{tribe.Updated}}</h2>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-item>
```

But with the above code its not possible.
Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
The issue occurs because i was doing

```
 this.angularFire.database.list
```

for *getMyTribeDetailsByTribeId(tribeId)* method
instead of

```
this.angularFire.database.object
```

which in turn generated an additional array of objects like

```
 -array
     -array
        -object
     -array
         -object
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what exactly doesn't work. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I just found the issue and given an update on this above.