# Firebase Firestore - relational data design approaches

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm totally new to Firebase, and I'm trying to get my head round the best db model design for 'relational' data, both 1-1 and 1-many.

We are using the **Firestore** db (not the realtime db).

Say we have `Projects` which can contain many `Users`, and a `User` can be in multiple `Projects`

The UI needs to show a list of `Users` in a `Project` which shows things like `email`, `firstname`, `lastname` and `department`.

What is the best way to store the relationship?

- An array of `User` ids in the `Project` document?
- A map of Ids in the `Project` document?

Ive read the above approaches were recommended, but was that for *realtime database*? *Firestore* supports Sub Collections, which sound more appropriate...

- A sub collection of `Users` in the Project document?
- A separate collection mapping `Project` id to `User` id?
- A `Reference` data type? I've read here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types about `Reference` data type, which sounds like what I want, but I cant find any more on it!

If its just a map or array of Ids, how would you then retrieve the remaining data about the user?  Would this have to sit in the application UI?

If its a sub collection of Users documents, is there any way to maintain data integrity?  If a user changed their name, would the UI / a cloudFunction then have to update every entry of that users name in the Sub collections?

any help / pointers appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to using NoSQL databases, where everything you know is turned upside down in favor of scalability. :-)

I've provided answers to some of your questions below.

Answer (score 2):

The approach for modeling many-to-many relationships in Firestore is pretty much the same as it was in Firebase's Realtime Database, which I've answered here: [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase). The only difference is indeed that you can store the lookup list in a sub-collection of each project/user.

Looking up the linked item is also the same as before, it indeed requires loading them individually from the client. Such a client-side join is not nearly as slow as you may initially expect, so test it before assuming it can't possibly be fast enough.

Ensuring data integrity can be accomplished by performing [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) or using [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#updating_data_with_transactions). These either completely succeed or completely fail.

Comment: Awesome, just watched a few of your videos and it makes much more sense now.

Comment: So, in firestore, I can have a subcollection holding the list of users, rather than a separate lookup table at the root?

Comment: What is the benefit of using a Firestore data type of `Reference` over a plain string `uid`?