# Firebase Firestore : how to store and query One to Many relationships?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to add tags to documents in Firestore.

These tags are created by admin users, and each `Tag` is a document in a `Tags` collection.

One or more of these tags are then applied to other documents, say `Item` documents.

We then need to be able to query the `Items` for ones that contain a specific `Tag` id, and have other range filters - date created within a range, order by date created, user id matches a specific user etc.

How would I structure the `Item` tag data so it can be queried?

- An Array property can't be queried, so that wont work.
- A map or set must be pre indexed, which also won't work as its dynamic data.
- If I had a pre-defined number of allowable tags, and save each as a property, `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3` etc, I could try to query that, but `OR` is not supported...
- I could add another collection, that holds the one-to-many relationships

  - say `ItemTags`, that has `{itemId, tagId}`, and then Query that first to get a list of `Item` ids, but again, how do I then user that list of ids to filter the `Items` collection?

I don't want this client side as the data is going to be very large.

**UPDATE:**
The Tags are hierarchical, and you can only have one tag at each level.  So one possible option is to have top level fields on the `Item`: `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3` etc with a pre defined limit. Then when the `Item` is created, the correct tag levels are inserted, and when its queried, we would need to know which level tag the user is looking for and we could then query `item.tag1 = levelOneTag AND item.tag2 = levelTwoTag`.

Not ideal as it limits the level, but I'm pretty sure 10 would cover it.

Comment: In general with NoSQL databases, if your use-case can't be met with a certain data model, modify or augment the model so that it allows your use-case. When it comes to categorization of items, you'll often end up with a reverse "index": a collection where you can look up the items (or item IDs) for a specific category. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41528908 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40657455. While both were written for the realtime database, the principals apply to Cloud Firestore too.

Comment: I am currently looking at the exact same use case? Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, not really.  In the end we just mapped the data client side, far from ideal, but was the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to have a subcollection on each tag, with all the document IDs that have that particular tag. And also a subcollection on each document that lists all the tags that that document has.

What I have found with NoSQL and Firestore lately is that it is very fast and scalable with the downsize that you need to spend more time on updates.

I usually do this with triggers with firebase functions. Like for example you could add a listener when a tag is added/modified/deleted into a document sub collection and you update or delete that document ID in that particular tag sub collection. (ID or any other field that you need to filter)

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

That way you dont have that much client logic and you have everything in the backend which is easier to maintain.