# firebase work with the user nick name or the user id?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design

I'm new in firebase, I know in mysql we have a table `users` with a unique id (eg: 1, 2...).

If I have a table follow and I want to record who follows who, I add:

```
follow

1 3 // user_id 1 follows user_id 3
3 2
3 1
```

I'd like the best approuch in firebase real time database, I have a json users, with unique key too and username. And I have json follow:

follow:

```
CMypCAlwMXPeM8X07P0sKsO
 |
 --- randomkey
        |
        --- follow: UFPRK8GG4tMvCejEfqWiCE220Mv2
```

in other words, user `CMypCAlwMXPeM8X07P0sKsO` follow user `UFPRK8GG4tMvCejEfqWiCE220Mv2`.

In firebase, should I work with this unique users keys (like mysql) or should I use usernames? like:

```
josh
 |
 ... randomkey
        |
        --- follow: marie
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To model followers between users in Firebase Realtime Database, I typically end up with three top-level lists:

```
users: {
  uid1: { ... },
  uid2: { ... },
  uid3: { ... }
},
followers: {
  uid1: {
    uid2: true
  },
  uid2: {
    uid3: true,
  },
  uid3: {
    uid1: true
  }
},
followees: {
  uid1: {
    uid3: true
  },
  uid2: {
    uid1: true,
  },
  uid3: {
    uid2: true
  }
}
```

So you're essentially splitting your single `follow` table into two top-level lists: one for each "direction" of the relationship.

Also see:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [Firebase simple many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130311/firebase-simple-many-to-many-relationship)