# When use Firebase in Android, how to get a specific data by child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my Database looks like.

The table group has child "currentMembers"
[image: The table group has child "currentMembers"]

In "currentMember", the first string is userID, and the next one is a boolean. I want to select group which contain a specific userID.
My code is showing below.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("groups").orderByChild("currentMembers").equalTo(currentUserID);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UserGroup> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserGroup>()
                    .setQuery(query, UserGroup.class)
                    .build();
```

But it return nothing, how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
FirebaseDatabase
  .getInstance()
  .getReference()          
  .child("groups")
  .orderByChild("currentMembers/"+currentUserID)
  .equalTo(true);
```

But this won't scale very well, since you'll need to explicitly define an index for each member.

This typically means that you need to adapt your data model to include a map that allows the inverse lookup. So a node that allows looking up the list of groups for a particular user.

```
users
  $uid
    currentGroups
      $groupId: true
```

Also note that you're nesting multiple entity types in a single branch of your tree, which is an anti-pattern when it comes to the Firebase Database.

If you have two entity types Users and Groups and a many-to-many relationship between them, you'll end up with four top-level lists:

```
users
groups
userGroups
groupUsers
```

Also see my answers on these related questions:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)