# How to use orderedByChild with key and multiple values in iOS firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase realtime database with data like in below image[image]

user-ids key will have array of emails.How could i apply queryOrderedByChild with key and array of values in iOS

```
var ref = Database.database().reference().child(Constants.ACTIVES)
self.ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "user_ids").queryEqual(toValue: "krishna.vutti@gmail.com").observe(.value, with: { (snapShot) in {

})
```

in above query  toValue is accepting single string value but in my case it would be array of emails.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database API doesn't allow ordering/filtering on array contents.

If you want to be able to look up the "ACTIVES" for a specific user, you should add a node to your database where you keep the active ids for each user.

```
activesByUser
   uid1
     activeId1: true
     activeId2: true
   uid2
     activeId3: true
```

This means that you're keeping the relational information in both directions: both from active to users (which you already have) and from user to actives (with the structure I added). Keeping this information in both directions is quite common on NoSQL databases, because it makes looking up information in either direction incredibly simple

Also see my answers here:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)