# Retrieving data from Firebase when the parent of the child node is unknown

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app where you can send and get friend request. The database is structured as:

[image: link to image]

Now I want to build an "alert function" when someone sends you a friend request with an addValueEventListener so that I can see if the current user have a "recieved" in the database.
Something like:

```
mFriendRequestDatabase = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_req");
    mCurrent_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String current_user_id = mCurrent_user.getUid();
    mFriendRequestDatabase.child(current_user_id).addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The problem is that i can't reach to see if current user have a "sent" or a "recieved" since i don't know the ID of the person that sent the request.
dataSnapshot.child(???).child("sent" or "recieved")

How to I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could get some of this with a query, but it'll be tricky to keep the performance under control since you'll need to define an index on every user. For some of the problems with this see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested).

A better way is to separate the requests into two separate lists: the ones that were sent, and the ones that were received. E.g.

```
friend_requests
  uidOfChristoffer
    received
      uidOfPuf: true
    sent:
      uidOfSomeoneElse: true
 uidOfPuf
    sent
      uidOfChristoffer: true
 uidOfSomeoneElse
    received
      uidOfChristoffer: true
```

Now you can specifically get the ones that anyone has received by reading `/friend_requests/theirUid/received`. This is a more specific approach of a many-to-many relationship, so I also recommend reading my answer on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase).

Comment: I still don't get how this helps me? I can't reach the userID of the user that I recieved a request from? Or maybe I just don't understand.