# Filter array from from Firebase List

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app for an event using ionic+firebase, the agenda page shows the list of days and items for each day and the user can favorite each item so he can build his own agenda.

This is how my firebase dabase looks:

[image]

The user can switch between fullagenda and myagenda, so in myagenda I want to show just the items that the user has marked as favorites (in the database as you can see I save them with the userid and true).

I've been trying to filter the array that I get from the database but I don't know how to do it since every node has a different id (day1, day2, etc.. or e, d, f, g..)

The data is being retrieved succesfully from the database because I already built the fullagenda feature and its working good.

So my question is, how can I filter this array based on my database structure or even if you think that I should change the structure of the database and create a new collection where I save every single agenda item under a user id, something like this:

userid/day1/e/...

But in this case I will duplicate a lot of data for each user. I really dont know what to do :)

Thanks for your help & advise!

Comment: Your current data structure allows you to efficiently find the users for a given agenda item. It does not allow you to efficiently find the agenda items for a given user. For that you'll want to expand the data model to also have `/user_agendaitems/$uid/agendaitemid1: true`, etc. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680841/retrieving-data-from-firebase-when-the-parent-of-the-child-node-is-unknown/49681626#49681626

Comment: Note that duplicating data is completely normal in NoSQL database. If you're new to that, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much!! So I think that I will remove the usersSaved node from the agenda-items one and I will create /user_agendaitems/$uid/agendaitemid1: true. Thanks again!

Comment: Only remove it if you don't expect to need to find the "users who saved a specific agenda item".