# Firebase search for all objects that contain a value in a list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am attempting to search for all users who are a part of a given club/organization. I would have both the clubsOrgsId and clubsOrgsName. In the list of users these two data points are in an object named by the clubsOrgsId in a list called clubsOrgs, as seen below. Is this possible to do with a Firebase query; I would rather not run the search locally.

[image: Layout of Database]

This app is being written in Kotlin but an answer is appreciated regardless of programming language.

Answer (score 2):

Your current data structure allows your to efficiently find the club orgs for a given user. It does not allow you to efficiently find the users for a given club org. If you want that, consider adding an inverted data structure to allow it:

```
CLUBORGS
  $cluborgid
    users
      $uid: true
```

With this additional structure in place, the lookups are super easy.

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)