# How do I load/retrieve a Many to Many relationship in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, many-to-many

In my Android project I need Firebase to load/retrieve my list of 'children' (user with name) when retrieving an object (group) that is in a Many-to-Many relationship, like the structure below:

```
App {
   "users" : {
        "user123jsbgkjwroi" : {
            "name" : "Mr Guy", 
            "groups" : {
                "group567-alkfhhiuall_dajk" : true,
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    "groups" : {
        "group567-alkfhhiuall_dajk" : {
            "name" : "My Group 1",
            "groupShortCode" : "567",
            "groupPassPhrase" : "ABC",
            "members" : {
                 "user123jsbgkjwroi" : {
                     "A": 2,
                     "B": 1,
                     "C": 33
                 },
                 ...    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've likely made my life harder than necessary because I'm new to NoSQL, my group object uses the user as a map key, against another object which contains the list (A, B, C). Something like the following:

```
class Group {
    private String name;
    private Map<User, GroupItems> members;
}
```

When a new User joins the group, by entering the groupShortCode and groupPassPhrase I need to load the whole Group object, with the other Users (members) of the group.

But I do not want to do this recursively (I would rather fetch as few documents as possible - I should not load the User's other groups). Here's what I've tried:

```
dbReference.child("groups").orderByChild("groupShortCode").equalTo(...)
           .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        //TODO: Here I need load each User, but it means tons of calls   
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> profileKeys = dataSnapshot.child("members").getChildren();
        for (DataSnapshot keySnapshot : profileKeys) {
            dbReference.child("users").child(keySnapshot.getKey())
              .addListenerForSingleValueEvent( ... );
        }         

        //this constructor is because of the Object-to-Object Map so dataSnapshot.getValue() fails
        Group group = new Group(dataSnapshot, users);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        ...
    }

});
```

How do I do this properly, efficiently!?

Comment: It is more common to have four top-level lists for this scenario: `groups`, `users`, `groupUsers`, and `userGroups`. This allows you to load precisely what you need, at the cost at some extra code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase.  Aside from that: what's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: It just seemed to me like I must be doing something wrong. For my user to log in and then join a group with 8 users I'm going to make 10 or 11 individual requests. Seems like a lot of room for failure

Comment: What type of failure are you thinking of? It's quite some code, so definitely some room for mistakes there. But that's a one-time thing, where you should easily catch the errors during development. After that, all requests go over a single connection, so it's quite unlikely that one succeeds and other fails.

Comment: For example some 'User' call fails, or never returns at all (if that is possible - you've indicated not). Also because it's all asynchronous I have to wait and know when everything is loaded, before I construct my Group Object

Comment: All calls go over the same connection, so chances of one failing due to connection problems are no bigger with multiple calls than they'd be with a singe call. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you feel like adding it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more common to have four top-level lists for this scenario: groups, users, groupUsers, and userGroups. This allows you to load precisely what you need, at the cost at some extra code. See [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase).

If you're worried about problems, it may help to know that all requests go over a single connection, so it's quite unlikely that one succeeds and other fails. Chances of one failing due to connection problems are no bigger with multiple calls than they'd be with a singe call. See [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)