# Firebase database how to know where a user is to edit values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a structure where I need to login with an user below a certain parent and I need to know in which parent I'm in order to modify that parent and my user id, here is my database structure

[image]

Now, Im login to the app with one of the users id below users node, now, I need to know the parent for that user in order to modify that user below that parent

Example

I login with the user `RgF82BBZXhahtgYeZDWXwCk1q6b2`  , now I need to know that is inside `9MmrGOJz9ePksi....` parent in order to add data inside that parent and inside that user

Tried this code but it only do it for a random key and not for the key containing that user

```
mDatabase.child("MyApp").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String key = snapshot.getKey();

                    mDatabase.child("MyApp").child(key).child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("apples").setValue("3");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current data structure there is no efficient way to look up the parent of a known user ID. The Firebase database doesn't support querying for the existence of a specific value in a list.

As is common with NoSQL databases, the solution is to add an additional data structure that *does* allow your user case. In this case that would be a simple inverse lookup, where the user ID is the key, and the parent key is the value.

Something like:

```
userLookup
  RgF82BBZXhahtgYeZDWXwCk1q6b2: 9MmrGOJz9ePksi.... 
  dRnalqAWm3............MM6vb2: 9MmrGOJz9ePksi....
```

Now you can easily look up the parent key for a given user ID, and then find their data in the existing structure.

For some more data modeling tips, see:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

Comment: Thanks a lot Puf ! I just added an answer below on how I solved it :)

Comment: Good to hear that you got it solved Todd. And thanks for sharing. For future questions, please post the JSON as text and not as a screenshot, so that we can copy/paste it more easily. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone interested I solved the issues like Puf suggested

First I created the lookupTable

[image]

And then a minor calls to get it done

```
 mDatabase.child("MyApp").child("userLookup").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String key = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mDatabase.child("MyActivity").child(key).child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("apples").setValue(3);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```