# Firebase Java Admin SDK beginner from SQL

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a client's Point-of-Sales (POS) software. I was going to use django with MySQL but the client can't pay for a host, so I decided to write it in Java with Firebase. I'm having some trouble thinking in terms of Firebase coming from MySQL.

According to the Firebase documentation, to do relations like I would in SQL, it would have to look like:

```
inventory : {
    CD001 : {
        genre : {
            "CLASSICAL" : TRUE
    }
}
genre : {
    CLASSICAL : {
        Name : "CLASSICAL"
        inventory : {
            CD001 : TRUE
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas in SQL I would just put the genre `primary key` as a `foreign key` in inventory. Is there a better way to do this in Firebase? It seems for every product that has the genre `CLASSICAL` I would have to make two `updateChildAsync()`. Also, any changes (like removing a genre from inventory) I would also have to loop through two `DatabaseReference`.

If I were to use `push` to get the generated `primary key` it would be even worse because I would have to loop through each child just to get the `genre` name.

I know this may not be the optimal way to make a POS, but given the constraints of the project and that I like learning new stuff, I'm going to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

In NoSQL you will often have the same values in multiple places, to allow the specific use-cases of your app. This is normal, but may take some getting used to if you're coming from a background in relational databases.

To get to grips with Firebase's NoSQL model, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) (for Firebase Realtime Database) and [Getting to know Clouf Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ).

For a good example of how to model many-to-many relationships, see [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase). Your example looks more like a categorization problem, in which case I also recommend reading [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value).