# Remove a child's child having said child's id

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

So I have this structure:

[image]

And my question is: How can I remove every field with the id of `3Q41X2tKUMUmiDjXL1BJon70l8n2` from every subject. I'm thinking about something like this:

```
admin.database().ref('UsersBySubjects')
    .child('subjects')
    .child(/variable/)
    .child(uid).remove().catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hers the below code that should make it possible to do what you are trying. Basically just a query to get all the id's, the remove is a promise so you would probably want to add in async await to deal with promises to make sure its actually deleted before going to the next one

```
admin.database().ref('UsersBySubjects/subjects')
                .orderByChild('3Q41X2tKUMUmiDjXL1BJon70l8n2')
                .equalTo('3Q41X2tKUMUmiDjXL1BJon70l8n2')
                .on('value', (snapshot) => {
                    snapshot.forEach((result) => {
                       result.ref.remove()
                    })
                 })
```

Comment: While this works, it requires that you define an index on each UID property. For a more scalable solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase.

Comment: Very valid point. I tend to use Firestore exclusively now, much better query capabilities

Comment: There you'd use the new `array-contains` family of operators for this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html I really need to start using those myself, but... time :-/