# only delete an object in firebase if it does not appear in another object

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Here is my firebase data structure:

```
item:
    itemUID:
        Title: ""
        createdBy: userUID

media:
    mediaUID:
        Title: ""
        createdBy: userUID
        items:
            itemUID: true
            itemUID: true

user:
    userUID:
        firstname: ""
        lastname: ""
```

I would like the current user to edit one of their media lists. the media is basically a bunch of items and a title and who the media was created by, which is the current user. Other users can add the current user's items to their media and a reference to that item appears in "items" in the media. When the current user edits their media and wants to delete an item from the media, I would like to only delete the item if

1. it was created by the current user
2. it is not in anyone else's media

how would I go about doing this in swift?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your current data structure it is very easy to find the list of media for a specific user. But it is quite hard to find the list of users for a specific media item. For your type of use-case you'll typically want to store the information in both directions: items per user, and users per item.

So I'd add two more top-level lists:

```
users_media
  $uid
    $mediaid1: true
    $mediaid2: true
media_users
  $mediaid
    $uid1: true
    $uid2: true
```

With these additional structures, your use-case becomes a bunch of reads of lists, and corresponding multi-location updates.

Also see:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [Introducing multi-location updates and more](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)
- [Client-side fan-out for data consistency](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html) (showing more samples of multi-location updates)

Comment: I will have a look into doing this!