# Firebase: Querying data inside an unknown name key (child inside another child)

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a React Native app and having a query doubts.

I need to return all **groups** (eg "group-id-01"), where the provided **UID** exists within **members**.

[image: Firebase]

This code return all groups:

```
const memberGroup = firebase.database().ref('groups')
memberGroup.once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
          console.log('snapshot');
          console.log(snapshot.val());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Erro');
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Result I'm having:

```
"group-id-01"
  "members"
    "no-uid-provided":"Belem"
    "oZlTzlbCTGaZfsrzyxqABlnxt2e2":"Julia"
  "name":"Rolling Stones"
```

Result I want:

```
"group-id-01"
  "members"
    "oZlTzlbCTGaZfsrzyxqABlnxt2e2":"Julia"
  "name":"Rolling Stones"
```

Whell...

I've tried some queries with .orderByChild and .equalTo, but the result is null.

```
const memberGroup = firebase.database().ref('groups')
.orderByChild('oZlTzlbCTGaZfsrzyxqABlnxt2e2')
.equalTo('Julia')

memberGroup.once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
          console.log('snapshot');
          console.log(snapshot.val());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Erro');
          console.log(error);
        });
```

I'm new in Firebase and I don't know if is possible to query a **child inside another child with unknown name**.

Appreciate all the help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current structure allows you to easily look up the members for a given group. It does not allow you to easily look up the groups for a given user. To allow the latter, you will need to add an *additional* data structure (often called a reverse index) mapping users back to groups.

```
userGroups
  uid1
    groupid1: true
    groupid2: true
  uid2
    groupid2: true
    groupid3: true
```

This means that you're duplicating data to allow for the additional use-case, which is quite common in NoSQL databases.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)

Comment: That's my first NoSql project and duplicate data is really hard to my "SQL" mind. 
Thanks a lot Frank!

Comment: Yeah, it also took me some time to get used to. I talked a bit about that in my talk about building geoquerying on top of Firestore: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q. At some point it became second nature though, so I hope you have the same experience.