# Query firebase realtime database where child has property

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query my Firebase Realtime Database to find all games a user belongs to.

I have a list of `games`, each game has a property of `players`. Each child of `players` has a key of `$uid`, and within that `{key: $uid, name: "joe"}`

Is it possible to get all games this way? Or do I need to start keeping another index of `players_games/$uid/$game`?

I've tried `firebase.database().ref('games').orderByChild('players').equalTo(token.uid)`, but this yields `null`

It looks like `database.ref('games').orderByChild('players/${token.uid}')` works, but then I'd need to give `.read` access to all of `games`, or do this server-side.

[image: tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current data structure makes it easy to find all the users for a specific game. It does not however make it easy to find all the games for a specific user. To allow that, you'll want to add an addition data structure that inverts the information.

So that'd look something like this:

```
player_games: {
  "XDYNyN8il6TDsM4LuttwDzNuytj1": {
    "-M5vf...U5zK": true
  },
  "NxH14...mxY2": {
    "-M5vf...U5zK": true
  }
}
```

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)

---

I recommend you also study the Firebase documentation on [structuring your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), specifically the section on [avoiding nested data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data). By mixing entity types as you currently do, you'll likely run into problems with security, and scalability.

The most idiomatic way to model your many-to-many relationship in the Firebase database is with four top-level lists:

```
players: {
  $playerId: { ... }
}
games: {
  $gameId: { ... }
}
player_games: {
  $playerId: {
    $gameId: true
  }
}
game_players: {
  $gameId: {
    $playerId: true
  }
}
```

Also see:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)

Comment: thanks! if Firebase's database weren't so easy, I'd be more upset that I'm recreating all the noSQL relationships manually myself :-)

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Sometimes it feels a bit like you're creating your own database on top of an awesome realtime synchronized JSON tree. :)