# How will the project Structure look like

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

How will the project structure look like on FirebaseDatabase.i got it from an open source code but i cant figure it out how will this look like

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Query dbQuery = database.getReference("teachers-courses").orderByChild("teacherNo").equalTo(uid);
```

and this

```
dbQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot courseSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String course = courseSnapshot.child("courseNo").getValue().toString();
            courses.add(course);
        }

        // Resolve query for courses names.
        Query coursesQuery = database.getReference("courses");

        // Event listenere to update.
        coursesQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot courseSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // Grab the key.
                    String key = courseSnapshot.getKey();
                    // If key is required.
                    if (courses.contains(key)){
                        String courseName = courseSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        coursesName.add(courseName);
                    }
                }

                // Fill the list.
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        CourseTeacherActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        coursesName );

                // Set the adapter.
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

this is a source code from github and was trying to figure it out for days now but i cant seem to figure it out i will appreciate if you can show me what the project structure would look like in Firebase Database thank you in advance

Comment: do you mean the database's structure?

Comment: @Ticherhaz yes i mean the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you shared seems to load the courses for a specific teacher, but first loading the course IDs for that teacher, and then loading the course data.

Let's see what we can determine about the JSON structure from the code:

1. The `database.getReference("teachers-courses").orderByChild("teacherNo").equalTo(uid)` indicates:

   1. That there is a child `teachers-courses` under the root.
   2. That each child node under there has a property `teacherNo` with a UID as its value.
   3. This typically means that the nodes directly under `teachers-courses` use a push ID as their key.
2. The `courseSnapshot.child("courseNo").getValue().toString()` then shows that each child node has a `courseNo` property.
3. The `database.getReference("courses")` shows that there's another top-level node `courses` that contains the courses. At this point it becomes clear that we have a fairly standard many-to-many relationship, as for example explained here: [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
4. The `courseSnapshot.getKey();` indicates that the key for each node under `/courses` is the ID for that course.
5. The `courseSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString()` shows that each course has a name property.

All of this combined brings us to the following JSON:

```
"teachers-courses": { // 1.1
  "somepushid": { // 1.3
    "teacherNo": "someteacherid" // 1.2
    "courseNo": "somecourseid" // 2
  }
},
"courses": { // 3
  "somecourseid": { // 4
    "name": "The name of the course" // 5
  }
}
```

There is likely to be more data in the database, but this is what is being used by the code you shared.