# Show Firebase User Likes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I list the car brands as follows. I keep the cars the user likes in a separate table. How can I list the cars that the user likes with their features? I am using firebase realtime database.

```
{
cars:{
  {"id" : 1, "title" : "BMW"},
  {"id" : 2, "title" : "Toyota"}
  },
  likes:{
    "1":{user1: true, user2: true},
    "2":{user1: true},
  }
}
```

How should my table JSON layout be?

I studied the [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase) question, but I could not understand how to get the car information.

Comment: This is a fairly traditional many-to-many relationship, for which I recommend creating as many "connector tables" as you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41527058. With that you can then load the data pretty easily. If you're struggling with that part, please edit your question to [show what you've already tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I studied that question but could not understand.@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: It is really hard to help with "I could not understand", as that's the best explanation of the concepts that I know off. Hence the request to show what you've already tried in code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `features` tree, or table as you call it, so as to avoid nesting data. In terms of recording a users feature `preferences` that would be yet another JSON tree, or table, of data.

```
{
cars:{
  {"id" : 1, "title" : "BMW"},
  {"id" : 2, "title" : "Toyota"}
  },
  likes:{
    "1":{uid1: true, uid2: true},
    "2":{uid1: true},
  },
  features:{
    "f1":{sunroof: true, bluetooth: true},
    "f2":{offroad: true},
  },
  preferences:{
    "uid1":{f1: true, f2: true},
    "uid2":{f1: true},
  }
}
```