# How to get direct parent's key in Firebase real-time database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now I am building a React ecommerce website.
And now I am in the cart page. In the cart page, if user click the first product, I want to show all rest 2 products products.
How to get all products of special store that has special id as key? In the image, I want to get 3 red right arrows' products.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is currently possible. With your current data structure you can easily find the products for a known store ID, but not the store ID for a known product ID.

The reasons is that `orderByKey()` requires that the keys are directly under the path you query, and you don't know the store ID, and `orderByChild()` requires that the value lives at a known/fixed path under each direct child node of the path, which also isn't the case here.

The common approach is to create a reverse data structure, where you map product IDs to store IDs.

That could like like this (if each product has a single store):

```
ProductStores: {
  "-M_ProductId": "A4_StoreId"
}
```

And like this (if each product can exist in multiple stores):

```
ProductStores: {
  "-M_ProductId": {
    "A4_StoreId": true,
    "A5_StoreId": true
  }
}
```

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this answer. Thank you for your help.