# How to get all objects that contains a specific value in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database image]

I have a firebase database looking like this would like u get all calendar events objects that contains a specific user emails by the email like: "admin@live.dk"

I need this so I can show each user what events they have joined in the calendar

Comment: Your current data structure makes it easy to find the users for a specific date/event. It does not make it easy to find the events for a specific user. To allow that you will need to add an additional data structure, that sort of inverts what you currently have: mapping each user (UID/email) to their list of events. For examples of this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase

Comment: thanks alot for it :) i will take a look at it

Comment: const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
        firebaseDB
              .database()
              .ref("calendar/events")
              .on("value", (snapshot) => {
                let data = [];
                snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                  data.push(child.val());
                });
                setArr(data);
              });

then you can do this

    var returned = [];
    arr.forEach((snapshot)=>{
    if(snapshot.0.users.0.user_email==="admin@live.dk"){
    returned.push(snapshot);
    }
    });

Comment: testing it at the moment by cant get the this to work cus of "0" if(snapshot.0.users.0.user_email==="admin@live.dk")