# Remove value from Firestore Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete the yellow user in the screenshot if he decides to delete his account. The blue X is a different user. How do I do that?

In the second picture is my attempt. I don't know how to get the userid of the blue X.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your current data structure makes it easy to find the yellow `Followers` for a given blue `Follow` node. It does not however make it easy to find the blue node for a given yellow one. In fact, to allow that you will have to read all blue nodes, and check each individual `Followers` child node in turn.

To more easily allow your use-case, you'll want to also store the inverse data structure that allows you to find the blue `Follow` nodes for a given yellow `Follower` value. I typically refer to this as the `Followee` map, although I admit I'm not sure if that's even a word:

```
Followees: {
  "ky....Yhi1": {
    "L5w...6rF3": true
  }
}
```

Now with this structure, you can find the "L5w...6rF3" key based on knowing the "ky....Yhi1" value and delete the user from the `Followers` node there.

We covered this scenario a few times before, so I recommend also checking out:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)