# how to filter orderby nested list firebase to flutter App with rest database realtime

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase database filter orderBy seller_id in nested list, why is the result null? thank you

[image: 1]:[rules Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjxvc.png)

```
var url = Uri.parse(
    'https://MeDatabase.firebasedatabase.app/orders.json?auth=$authToken&orderBy="list_produk/seller_id"&equalTo="$idUser"');

try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
    throw EasyLoading.showError('Cek Koneksi Internetmu!');
  }
  final extractData =
      convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print('inii orderan');
  print(extractData);
  if (extractData == null) {
    return _orders = [];
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```

[image: Null value]

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to index and order each order on its `list_produk/seller_id` property.

But if I look at your JSON data, there is no `list_produk/seller_id` property under the order. There's only `list_produk/1/seller_id`, and presumably `list_produk/0/seller_id`. Those are not the same as what you use in your rules/query, so the query returns no results.

Firebase Realtime Database queries function on a single, flat list of nodes. The value you order/filter on must exist at a fixed path under each direct child node.

So in your example, you can search across all orders on for example `id_user`, or you can search across the `seller_id` of the products in a specific order, but you can't search across all sellers of products in all orders.

In other words: your current data structure makes it easy to find the products and sellers per order, it does however not make it each to find the orders per product across all users. To allow that you'll want to add an additional data structure, typically known as a reverse index, that maps from each `seller_id` to the orders that contain products from that seller.

For more on this, I recommend checking out:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)