# How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database conditionally

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assume that I have the following structure in my Firebase Realtime database:

```
- users
  - g123
    - john
      - age: 30
      - active: 1
    - mike
      - age: 20
      - active: 0
    - johanna
      - age: 30
      - active: 1
  - g456
    - jake
      - age: 20
      - active: 1
    - maria
      - age: 20
      - active: 0
  - g789
    - elli
      - age: 20
      - active: 0
    - joe
      - age: 20
      - active: 0
```

I need to get the list of child:s where there is at least 1 user with **active** set to **1**.

So, in the example above, there are 2 active users in **g123** and 1 active user in **g456**. And there is no active user in **g789**.

How do I build a query to Firebase Realtime database (preferably with Python) that will return **g123** and **g456**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries work on a flat list of nodes, and the value to order/filter on must be at a fixed path under each direct child node. So the sort of query you want, is not possible on this data structure.

A common workaround is to store the `activeCount` under each direct child node, and update that upon each write.

```
- users
  - g123
    activeCount: 3
    - john
      - age: 30
      - active: 1
    - mike
      - age: 20
      - active: 0
    - johanna
      - age: 30
      - active: 1
  - g456
    activeCount: 0
    - jake
      - age: 20
      - active: 1
    - maria
      - age: 20
      - active: 0
  - g789
    activeCount: 3
    - elli
      - age: 20
      - active: 0
    - joe
      - age: 20
      - active: 0
```

You can then order/filter on this `activeCount`.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.