# Firebase Realtime Database orderByChild data structure - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having issues querying data with `orderByChild`. I would like to query all tasks where provided userID matches any approver id. Task ID is autogenerated so I need to flatten this structure somehow.
Each task has two approvers, and each approver has status, timestamp, id.

Any idea on how to flatten it so I can take advantage of `orderByChild`?

```
Tasks:{
  "df234dgkjsf234" : {
   "approvers" : {
      "4U1D23dfsdf23e" : {
        "id" : "4U1DWf95rJvgfAwDYs7m",
        "status" : "pending",
        "timestamp" : "pending"
      },
      "sdf32fdsf34sdg3" : {
        "id" : "FXRkK22TjyxKV6z4UkrU",
        "status" : "pending",
        "timestamp" : "pending"
      }
    },
    "reason" : "test",
    "requester" : "4U1DWf95rJvgfAwDYs7m",
    "requesterName" : "Dana Mayers",
    "status" : "pending",
    "tagetValue" : "QT1IkGHS3mmalyXqdCuD",
    "taskName" : "Title Change",
    "timestamp" : 1644773238,
    "value" : "New Title"
  },
"d4S34FSAdsf43FM" : {
   ...
  }
}
```

I want to make ideally one query to get this data as opposed to querying by `Approver1` and then by `Approver2`

```
Tasks:{
  "df234dgkjsf234" : {
    "Approver1" : "4U1DWf95rJvgfAwDYs7m",
    "Approver1status" : "pending",
    "Approver1timestamp" : "pending"
    "Approver2" : "FXRkK22TjyxKV6z4UkrU",
    "Approver2status" : "pending",
    "Approver2timestamp" : "pending",
    "reason" : "test",
    "requester" : "4U1DWf95rJvgfAwDYs7m",
    "requesterName" : "Dana Mayers",
    "status" : "pending",
    "tagetValue" : "QT1IkGHS3mmalyXqdCuD",
    "taskName" : "Title Change",
    "timestamp" : 1644773238,
    "value" : "New Title"
  },
"d4S34FSAdsf43FM" : {
   ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with one query, since you're looking for two separate values. The closest you can get is by doing two separate queries on (`4Approver1` and `Approver2` in) the second data structure, and then merging the results in your application code.

The alternative is to add a secondary data structure, where you map from the user ID back to the tasks they're allowed to approve:

```
UserTasks: {
  "4U1D23dfsdf23e": {
    "df234dgkjsf234": true,
    "d4S34FSAdsf43FM": true
  },
  "sdf32fdsf34sdg3": {
    "df234dgkjsf234": true
  }
}
```

With such an additional structure you can easily find the tasks for a specific UID, and then load the task details for each.

For more on this, I recommend also reading:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)