# Firebase realtime rule access parent based on child value

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

There are many posts about firebase realtime rule but I still cannot solve my problems.

This is my data. There may be multiple "GId" or multiple "User" or multiple "caregiver".

[image]

I want to grant access to "GId" if a specific value exists in "caregiver". My following rule does not work.

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "GId": {
      "$GId": {
        ".write": "data.child('User').child('caregiver').child('-N0Uy6K55bQlkPuuoioA').exists() ",
        ".read": "data.child('User').child('caregiver').child('-N0Uy6K55bQlkPuuoioA').exists()",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I change the rule to grant access to "GId" if a specific value exists in "User", it works.
Could you please show me what is wrong with my first rule?

Is it possible to grant other "GId" access to only some "User" in another "GId"?

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "GId": {
      "$GId": {
        ".write": "data.child('User').child('6e42092aa73f47f48657fe7f3a9610c5').exists() ",
        ".read": "data.child('User').child('6e42092aa73f47f48657fe7f3a9610c5').exists() ",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a query on a path in the Realtime Database checks for the value you specify at a specific, known path under each direct child node of the path where the query runs.

In your second set of rules, you specify the full path of the child whose existence you care about, so the rule can find the node at `User/6e42092aa73f47f48657fe7f3a9610c5` under the `$GId`. In the first set of rules however the `6e42092aa73f47f48657fe7f3a9610c5` is not in the path you look at, and there is no node at `User/caregiver/-N0Uy6K55bQlkPuuoioA` directly under `$GId`.

To make the rules work you will need to flatten your data structure, and possibly set up an inverse index so that you can look up whether access is allowed given the information that you **do** know. I'd also recommend reconsidering the [nesting of multiple data types in a single branch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) in your data structure, as it's a common antipattern and Firebase recommends [keeping the data flat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures).

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)