# Query based on grandchild

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a project returning data from IOT devices in different rooms. The data is set up as:

```
<firebase_url>
  |-<room_id>
  |  |-<report_id>
  |  |  |-<data>
  |  |
  |  |-<report_id>
  |     |-<data>
  |
  |-<room_id>
```

I want to be able to query based on info in the `<data>` but it keeps telling me I need an index. The problem is that the room id's aren't hard coded. They're set from the devices. Is there a way to do this without needing to add an index for every new room added?

Comment: In addition to Frank van Puffelen's answer, you can also consider using Cloud Firestore and use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database can order/filter nodes at a path on a value that exists on a fixed, known path under each direct child node.

So in your data structure that means that you can query a specific room for data in the individual reports, but you can't query across all reports of all rooms. If you want that, consider either unnesting the data into a flat list, or creating an **additional** flat list of the nodes to allow this query.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)