# Firebase Realtime Database: Using "indexOn" with Nested Dynamic Id?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have written some delete queries for a Realtime Database in Firebase, but keep running into issues due to a lack of indexing.

Here is an example of the data structure for one of the collections:

```js
"followers": {
  "user_id1": {
     "user_ida": {
       "field1": "string val",
       "field2": true,
       "user_id": "user_ida"
     },
     "user_idb": {
       "field1": "string val",
       "field2": false,
       "user_id": "user_idb"
     }
  }
  "user_id2": {
    "user_idc": {
       "field1": "string val",
       "field2": true,
       "user_id": "user_idc"
     },
     "user_idd": {
       "field1": "string val",
       "field2": false,
       "user_id": "user_idd"
     }
  }
}
```

I want to query the collection by the nested user_ids, so that I can delete users from the lists that are no longer in our system. In my staging environment, the query works, and looks like this::

```js
const userId = 'my_user_id_input';

const rt_ref = await app.database().ref('followers')
  .orderByChild(`${userId}/user_id`)
  .equalTo(userId)

const rt_proc = new BatchProcessor(rt_ref);
const rt_proms = [];

await rt_proc.forEach(key_id => {
  console.log(`key_id = ${key_id}`);
  rt_proms.push(app.database()
          .ref(collectionName)
          .child(key_id)
          .child(userId)
          .remove()
          .then(() => println(`    Successfully deleted user_id from Realtime "followers" where parent_id was ${key_id}`))
          .catch((err) => {
            println(`    Error deleting Realtime "followers" for parent ${key_id} where ${userId} is child id: ${err}`);
          }));
});

return Promise.all(rt_proms);
```

However ... because part of the query is dynamic -- `${userId}/user_id` -- this results in a warning to add an ".indexOn" rule to my followers collection in the Realtime database::

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "my_user_id_input/user_id" at /followers to your security rules for better performance.

I've tried throwing everything at this in the Rules, but I've not been able to get anything to work. I'm stumped. Do I need to structure my query differently?

Here's what I've got at the moment in the Rules for this collection:

```js
/* NOTE: FIGURE OUT INDEX FOR NESTED USER_ID! */
    "followers": {
      "$followed_id": {
        "$follower_id": {
          ".write": "(auth != null)",
          ".indexOn": ["user_id", ".value"]
        },
        ".indexOn": [
          "timestamp",
          "user_name",
          "user_id",
          ".value"
        ]
      },
      ".read": "true",
      ".indexOn": ["user_id", ".value"]
    },
```

Granted, there are way too many "indexOn" entries in that collection, but I'm just trying as much as I can to see what will work.

I need to have this index to work, because we have a large amount of data in our PRODUCTION database, and this code just times out when it is run there :(.

Is there a solution for what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database can only query on a flat list of nodes, where the value to order/filter on is at a fixed path under each direct child node. That means that the `.orderByChild(`${userId}/user_id`)` query in your use-case is **not** possible, unless you can enumerate all possible values of `userId` in your security rules.

What you have is an index that makes it easy for you to find the followers for a given UID. But the use-case you have is to find the followees for a given UID, which your current data structure does not allow you to do.

What you need for this is an **additional** so-called reverse index, pretty much the exact inverse of what you have now. For the data you have, that'd be:

```
"followees": {
  "user_ida": {
    "user_id1": true
  },
  "user_idb": {
    "user_id1": true
  },
  "user_idc": {
    "user_id2": true
  },
  "user_idd": {
    "user_id2": true
  },
}
```

And with that you can find the followees under `/followees/$userId`.

Also see:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)

Comment: Thank you for this fast and detailed response, @Frank! It's good to know there's no good way for me to get to those child ids. Just, grrr, how to remove them when it's time to purge inactive users??

Comment: Just in code, by performing the inverse operation of when you create them.

Comment: I'm going to have to sit and dwell on this a bit. We do have a "following" collection, but I do not think that we connect "followers" and "following" in any useful way, so, unless I forcibly remove the child user_ids, deleted users still appear to follow active users.

I will take a deeper dive into Many to Many relationships (Firebase style -- I'm well versed in "normal" dbs :-) ) -- and see if I can wrap my head around your advice. Thank you so much for helping me battle through this logic!

Comment: Whatever the names of the nodes: you have a structure that seem to model "who do I follow?", but a use-case "who follows me?". In NoSQL databases you often need to change/expand your data model for the use-cases of your app, hence adding the inverse data here. --- If you're new to NoSQL, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).